# My Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inputForm .inputbox input').focusout(function() {
    var text_val = $(this).val();

    if (text_val === "") {
      $(this).removeClass('has-value');

    } else {
      $(this).addClass('has-value');

    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  background: none;
  border: solid 2px #21a1e1;
  color: #21a1e1;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input:focus,
input:active {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #21a1e1;
}

.inputbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.inputbox input {
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

.inputbox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}

.inputbox input:focus+label,
.inputbox input.has-value+label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="inputForm">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text">
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

im trying to make an floating label in my form but it seems my javascript is not
working.

[this is my output, the label should not go down when i click away from textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6N61.png)

Comment: `$('.inputForm .inputbox input').focusout`?

Comment: you're missinng a `.` before `focusout`

Comment: This is JQuery, which is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting. You might want to tag that to get more people who specialize in JQuery

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser console?

Comment: nope, but my floating label just doesn't work

Comment: You maybe want to change the title, the question as it is won't help anybody but you

Comment: What is the "floating label" ? which element is that and how do you want it to be?

Comment: apparently it seems to be a CSS problem and you don't even posted any code related to CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your developer console because as  Ghostrydr says your syntax is wrong. You are missing a "." before focusout like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.inputForm .inputbox input').focusout(function(){

    var text_val = $(this).val();

    if(text_val === "") {
      $(this).removeClass('has-value');

    } else {
      $(this).addClass('has-value');

    }

  });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vmzzhea/18/

Comment: Updated my post :)